# How to predefine fixed values in one of the columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I am trying to build a virtual warehouse. One of the columns in the database will contain a list of locations within the warehouse which is supposed to have fixed values. The warehouse is split into aisles DA to GA and each aisle is split into locations 011 to 603. There is a transverse aisle crossing all the aisles, eliminating certain locations (I am actually coming from a real existing warehouse). Other columns are name of product, product weight and quantity. My migration code looks like this:

```
  def change
create_table :locations do |t|
  t.string :location # this column is supposed to have fixed values
  t.string :product   # name of a product like CocaCola Zero 8x2L
  t.decimal :product_weight
  t.integer :quantity

  t.timestamps
end
```

In a separate document I made a class called Locations and I have method called def numbers_letters within this class that generates the list of locations:

```
def numbers_letters
  @digit = 3
  aisle_number = 0
  odd_list = []
  even_list = []
  for @letter in "DA".."GA"
    aisle_number = aisle_number + 1
    @letter.next!
    while @digit < 604
      @digit += 8
      if aisle_number.odd?
        odd_list << @digit
      else
        even_list << @digit
      end
      @digit += 2
      if aisle_number.odd?
        odd_list << @digit
      else
        even_list << @digit
      end
    end
    @digit = 3
    odd_list.each do |odd|
      if odd > 350 && odd < 604
        od = format('%003d', odd)
        $list_of_locations << @letter + od
      elsif odd < 322 && odd > 3
        od = format('%003d', odd)
        $list_of_locations << @letter + od
      end
    end
    even_list.each do |even|
      if even > 300 and even < 604
        ev = format('%003d', even)
        $list_of_locations << @letter + ev
      elsif even > 3 and even < 262
        ev = format('%003d', even)
        $list_of_locations << @letter + ev
      end
    end
    odd_list = []
    even_list = []
  end
end
```

My goal is to make a page where user can pick up a location from an available list and set a product, its case's weight and quantity to this location. Later on I want to program distribution operations but for now let's just solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears to me that you are not looking for "default value" but rather a way how to show list of posibilities for that value in a view form.

```
# app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  def numbers_letters
    #  EdwardM code here
  end
end

# app/controllers/locations_controller.rb
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new params[:location]
    @location.save
    respond_with @location
  end
end

# app/views/locations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @location do |f| %>
  First name: <%= f.text_field :product %><br />
  Last name : <%= f.text_field :quantity %><br />
  location  : <%= f.select(:location, @location.numbers_letters) %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```

is this what you were looking for ?

if so note that maybe you should consider is to have 2 locations rather than generating enourmous list of all possible Letter-number combination

something like:

```
def change
  create_table :locations do |t|
    t.string :aisle  # CG
    t.string :location  # number
    t.string :product   # name of a product like CocaCola Zero 8x2L
    t.decimal :product_weight
    t.integer :quantity
    t.timestamps
end
```

therefore you will be setting:

```
location = Location.new(aisle: 'CG', location '123')
location.save
```

Note:

`@location.numbers_letters` is just demonstration, you should maybe consider to use class methods like

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.available_aisiles 
    "DA".."GA"
  end

  def self.available_locations
    '011'..'603'
  end
end

# and then call

Location.available_locations
Location.available_aisiles
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd refactor the code a lot first. Something along these lines:

```
def numbers_letters
  list_of_locations = []
  aisle_number = 0
  odd_list = []
  even_list = []

  ('DB'..'GB').each do |letter|
    aisle_number += 1

    rng = (11..604)
    rng.step(8).each do |digit|
      if aisle_number.odd?
        odd_list << digit << digit + 2
      else
        even_list << digit << digit + 2
      end
    end

    odd_list.each do |odd|
      list_of_locations << letter + format('%003d', odd) if odd > 350 || odd < 322
    end
    even_list.each do |even|
      list_of_locations << letter + format('%003d', even) if even > 300 || even < 262
    end
  end

  list_of_locations
end
```

That is, use `each` instead of for, and take advantage of `range` and `step`. Also one should not use global vars or instance variables here, as they are for local use only. Just plain local variables are ok. So the code was changed a bit so that it returns list of locations instead of modifying global var, and you just use it as follows:

`list_of_locations = numbers_letters`

To add them to database:

```
class AddPredefinedLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # assumes class PredefinedLocation < ActiveRecord::Base in app/models
  def up
    create_table :predefined_locations do
      t.string :location
    end

    numbers_letters.each do |loc|
      PredefinedLocation.create location: loc
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :predefined_locations
  end
end
```

Comment: nice one!  I would never think of how simple the code can be. My code is working too but needlessly complicated. I will remember [range] and [step]. However, I still have no idea how to introduce list_of_locations into my [:locations] in my migrations. Or if it is that simple to type just t.string :location, default: list_of_locations, then where I am suppose to enter the code generating the list of locations?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your requirement but set the following in your migration file

t.string :location, **default: "Your value"**

Correct me If I am wrong in understanding your requirement.

Comment: I have just updated my question. Have look, you might understand now. What I basically want is a column with locations DA011, DA012.... DB011, DB12....... GA603. There is over 600 locations but from your answer I suppose I can do this: t.string: location, default: $list_of_locations .. Am I right?